# find match data inside the arrays by filtering

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my collection I have to find the operator_name match by date and inside array match by shift_name

```js
{
  "_id": "5eb301bc0218ff48b724a486",
  "date": "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "shift_wise": [{
      "_id": "5eb3037d3cb4d74b749fc22b",
      "shift_name": "Shift A",
      "operator_name": "5eb2ec3420fbc132eb648a6d"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5eb3037d3cb4d74b749fc22c",
      "shift_name": "Shift B",
      "operator_name": "5eb2ec3420fbc132eb648a6d"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5eb3037d3cb4d74b749fc22d",
      "shift_name": "Shift C",
      "operator_name": "5eb2ec3420fbc132eb648a6d"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-05-06T18:28:12.379Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-06T18:35:41.484Z",
  "__v": 4
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting ***input*** and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please post the attempts you made and details what is input and expected output

Comment: What is the desired output here, an object or something else?

Comment: here is an example 
``const result= obj.shift_wise.find(({shift_name, operator_name})=>  shift_name==='Shift A' && operator_name==='5eb2ec3420fbc132eb648a6d'); ``

Comment: @EugenSunic thank for the response I have to simply find operator_name in response by matching date and shift........................                                                                           i have a date and shift i find by date by using findOne({date: my date variale}) but I don't know how to match in array shift_name

Comment: What is `findOne` you need to be more elaborate in your descriptions.
What do you type into whatever you use to look for an operator and what is the response

Comment: Which date exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$shift_wise"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      date: "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "shift_wise.shift_name": "Shift A"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      operatorName: "$shift_wise.operator_name"
    }
  }
])
```

result:

```
{
    "operatorName": "5eb2ec3420fbc132eb648a6d"
  }
```

test: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yHfwOB3tlyx